# Do not recompile not changed files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation, visual-studio-2013

When I compile my application in release mode all files are recompiling even if they have no changes. But in debug mode only changed files are recompiling. How to fix release compilation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behaviour for VS, but I had this bug to not that long ago. 
I managed to fix it by deleting **all** temporary files, deleting the Release 
configuration, and recreating it. There's probably a simpler fix, but none I 
know of.